# Is it correct to use the verbs "want and understand" with present and past progressive?

Tags: tenses, verb-forms

It is very common to avoid using verbs such as 'want' and 'understand' with an -ing form. But l came across the following constructions:

- I'm 'understanding' French a lot better now.
- How many eggs were you 'wanting'?

My question is: is it correct to use the above-mentioned forms? If YES, why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct in American English.

*Why?* This is usually a bad question to ask. The answer is usually *because* or *because it is*.

First of all, the "rule" or even tendancy that you cite regarding the use (or non-use) of stative verbs in the *-ing form* is not an all-encompassing one. There is probably no stative verb in English that cannot be used in the *-ing form* given the proper context. To restate that, native speakers of (American) English use stative verbs in the *-ing form* all the time. We just don't use all stative verbs in the *-ing form* all the time, in the same way, in identical contexts. The two verbs you have given are acceptable uses in the given contexts.

Even the most stative of all verbs, *to be*, can be used in the *-ing form*, as in

> Look at Andy; *he's being* (*is being*) so nice to Amos right now.

Of course, speakers of Indian English use stative verbs in *-ing forms* a lot more often and in more contexts than do native speakers of American English.